# using jquery validate require_from_group with inputs and checkboxes, display just 1 message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with both text boxes and checkboxes, and need to validate if the user has entered data or checked at least 1.  I am using jquery validate on the rest of my form validation so would like to try to use this as well.  However I am getting multiple error messages when the checkbox is added.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/kkarp/3PxGE/ for demo

html:

```
<form class="form validateForm" method="get" action="Javascript: alert('Submitted');">
    this:
    <input type='text' name='address'  class="req1" />
    <br/>
    or this:
    <input type='text' name='address2' class="req1" />
    <br/>    
    or one of these:<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="aa" value="aa1" class="req1"/>aa1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="aa" value="aa2" class="req1"/>aa2<br />            

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('.validateForm').each(function () {
        $(this).validate({
            errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
                label.addClass('error');
                label.insertAfter(element);
            },
            wrapper: 'span'
        });
    });

    $('.req1').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            require_from_group: [1, ".req1"],
            messages: {
                require_from_group: 'Submission requires entry in at least one field.'
            }
        });
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you want one message for the entire group, you'll need to use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)...

```
groups: {
    myGroup: "address address2 aa"
}
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/3PxGE/1/

Comment: anyway to use class name in the groups option?  This is a very long form, subject to change often.

Comment: But you can create that group dynamically before you call validate, so it shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: I have a group of checkboxes but with unique names. This looks like it could work but how  would I dynamically add the names to the list?

Comment: @Nate, comments section is not the appropriate place to ask a new question.  It's possible.  Search my previous answers under the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.